# Is there a way to access Context in a Redux Thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk, react-context

This is more of an understanding question and I also want to know the community thoughts, rather than a code question.

We have a React App using `redux` for managing the global store and `redux-thunk` for dispatching actions. Now we want to **localize** the App and add a language switch. For that purpose I created a HOC which uses `React.Context` to store the dictionary for current language in it. And I wrapped all Components in this HOC - everything works just fine.

But we also need to **access to the dictionary in the thunks** to e.g. provide success/error messages after API calls in the selected language. It seems to be impossible without passing dictionary into thunks.

I've read a lot about Context API and when to use it and that it has different purpose than Redux. That's why I put the translations in the Context and not in the store, [mainly for this reason](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context). But now I'm getting the feeling that I missed something and should actually put the translations in the store instead to not be forced to pass the dictionary to the thunk every time I need it there. Is it so?

Or is there a way to implement something like `getContext` similar to `getState` from `redux-thunk`?

Comment: Is the dictionary static? Because if it is, it can be an independent module that you import where you need it. That way you decouple it from `redux` or the `context` api,  and can use it wherever you like. Or, you can try using the `withExtraArgument` option of `react-thunks`

Comment: @guzmonne no, it's not static, theres is a switch for changing the language. I'll take a look at `withExtraArgument `, thank you.

Comment: So doing something [like this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/redux-thunk-translate-4i4uw) is not an option? Sorry I couldn't find an example of how to use the `dictionary` or the `translate` function on the `thunk`.

Comment: @guzmonne it definitely is. Just to put translations in the state would work. But as I mentioned before, as I understood from the React docs, the "right" place for the translations would be the Context, but maybe I just misunderstood it.

Comment: In my opinion, a recommendation is that, you don't have to take it. One thing I would like to point is that I didn't put the translations in the state. They live as a separate object. The only thing I am keeping in the state is the `locale` key. The rest is just for the example. You could save the `locale` key on the `context` and apply the `translate` function at the component or `connect` level.

Comment: Hmm. But this way your components would not re-render if you switch the language. I think it's also the issue in codesandbox you linked. One could inject the `locale` key as a prop in each component though to force them re-render on language change.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why an unfinished version got saved. You can see now that it gets updated when you change the `locale`.